# Jquery datepicker is not binding in html Table to a input type text?

Tags: jquery, html

> I am using Jquery 1.9.1, Here is my code

```
<table>
   <tr>
                                        <th>Start Date</th>
                                        <td>
                                           <input type="text" id="ProtocoltxtStartDate"  style="width: 230px;" onclick="javascript:Plan.OpenCalender();" />
                                        </td>
 </tr></table>
```

> In Javascricpt, I have write as:

```
OpenCalender: function () {
    $('#ProtocoltxtStartDate').datepicker();
```

}

Please help

Comment: All .js files included? Where and how are you  calling '$("#ProtocoltxtStartDate").datepicker();'

Comment: I am using it on document.ready

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe:

```
<input type="text" id="ProtocoltxtStartDate"  style="width: 230px;"/>
```

+

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('#ProtocoltxtStartDate').datepicker();
});
```

should work.
You do not need to use onclick

Comment: Just increase the z-index of the datepicker div, then its works fine.$('#ui-datepicker-div').css('zIndex', 999999); Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> I am displaying datepicker calender on the 2nd div, i just incresed
>   the z-index of the datepicker calender div , its work fine. Thanks for
>   all who have response my question
>   $('#ui-datepicker-div').css('zIndex', 2147483647);